# URL Custom Rewrite

Tags: redirect, urls

How can i create a redirect **programatically**

from

```
http://www.myweb.com/myvendor/frame
```

to

```
http://www.myweb.com/wp-content/plugins/myvendor/frame.php
```

in my module?

I am trying

```
function myvendor_plugin_activate() {
    myvendor_plugin_rules();
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

function myvendor_plugin_deactivate() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

function myvendor_plugin_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^myvendor/frame/([a-zA-Z]+)$', 'wp-content/plugins/myvendor/frameoctmethod=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [QSA,L]', 'top');
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'myvendor_plugin_activate');
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'myvendor_plugin_deactivate');
add_action('init', 'myvendor_plugin_rules');
```

but not work and the rewrite rule does not appear in config table (rewrite_rules)

Any idea?

Comment: Do you have access to change .htaccess files?

Comment: Write a custom redirect in your config (.htaccess, nginx conf, ...) or use a plugin like [simple 301 redirects](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/)

Comment: yes i have access to .htacces

Comment: What is in your plugin file? You won't have access to the WordPress environment if you load the file directly.

Comment: i tried add_rewrite_rule but it not work

Comment: i have updated my question

Answer (score -2):

You can do something like

```
$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (home_url($path) == 'http://www.myweb.com/action/frame' ) {

    header('Location: ' . 'http://www.myweb.com/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/frame.php');

}
```

Comment: Code like this can get very very messy. Where would you even put it? WordPress introduces wrapper functions, so you don't need to use `header()` it will still work properly, etc